# How do I force Quarkus to use test/resources/ for a QuarkusIntegrationTest?

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing, junit5, quarkus

I'm using quarkus with jdbc + flyway and a frontend. Now I want to build an integration test with a dev services db and a selenium frontend test.

In tests annotated with `@QuarkusTest` I can see that the flyway scripts from `src/main/resources/db/migration/` and `src/test/resources/db/migration/` are executed.

But for the selenium frontend tests I need to annotate the tests with `@QuarkusIntegrationTest` and here only the flyway scripts from `src/test/resources/db/migration/` are executed. How can I add `src/main/resources/db/migration/` as well?

My setup:

```
Apache Maven 3.8.4
Java version: 11.0.13, vendor: Ubuntu, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.13.0-27-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

My pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.acme</groupId>
    <artifactId>getting-started</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
        <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus</quarkus.platform.group-id>
        <quarkus.platform.version>2.6.3.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
        <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- rest -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- db -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-agroal</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-flyway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-sqlserver</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- enable integration-tests -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My application.properties:

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=h2
quarkus.flyway.migrate-at-start=true
```

My (simplified) project structure:

```
src/
  main/
    java/
      [...]
    resources/
      db/
        migration/
          V1.0.0__init_db.sql // runs fine in @QuarkusIntegrationTests
    META-INF/
      [...]
    application.properties
  test/
    java/
      [...]
    resources/
      db/
        migration/
          V1.0.1__additional_DMLs.sql // is not executed in @QuarkusIntegrationTests
  pom.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That won't work with `@QuarkusIntegrationTest`, because this test actually executes the produced JAR and therefore the resources are loaded from inside the JAR itself and not the filesystem.